# Python code for finding shortest path between two GPS coordinates

Tags: python, gps

I have some GPS coordinates. How can I find the shortest path between two gps points by using python code or other?

Comment: Show us the code you have written to attempt solving this and the data (gps coordinates)

Comment: you mean to calculate the geodesic distance between two points? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425452/calculate-distance-between-two-lat-lon-alt-points-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If your points are closer together. Then i would just convert from WGS84 to ECEF:

```
ny_pos = [40.7648, -73.9808]  # GPS coords New York
la_pos = [34.0544, -118.2439] # GPS coords Los Angeles

def WGS84_to_ECEF(lat, lon, alt):
    # convert to radians
    rad_lat = lat * (np.pi / 180.0)
    rad_lon = lon * (np.pi / 180.0)
    a    = 6378137.0
    # f is the flattening factor
    finv = 298.257223563
    f = 1 / finv   
    # e is the eccentricity
    e2 = 1 - (1 - f) * (1 - f)    
    # N is the radius of curvature in the prime vertical
    N = a / np.sqrt(1 - e2 * np.sin(rad_lat) * np.sin(rad_lat))
    x = (N + alt) * np.cos(rad_lat) * np.cos(rad_lon)
    y = (N + alt) * np.cos(rad_lat) * np.sin(rad_lon)
    z = (N * (1 - e2) + alt)        * np.sin(rad_lat)
    return np.array([x, y, z])

ny_xyz = WGS84_to_ECEF(ny_pos[0], ny_pos[1], 0) 
la_xyz = WGS84_to_ECEF(la_pos[0], la_pos[1], 0) 

# Vector from NY to LA
la_xyz - ny_xyz
# array([3838314.23415231,   10238.84453052,  591228.02180622])
```

You can also get the distance between two GPS points with the haversine formula. This is to get the length for long distances on a sphere.:

```
def calc_haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    RADIUS = 6_367_000
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(np.radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    dist = 2 * RADIUS * np.arcsin(a**0.5)
    return dist
                                   
calc_haversine(ny_pos[0], ny_pos[1], la_pos[0], la_pos[1]) 
# 3934940.72281424 meters
```

Both functions return meters.